# Creating "ChristopheVersieux / HoloEverywhere" Seekbar

Tags: android

I tied to follow the example in 
https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere
to create Seekbar that is shown in below picture. However, it was too advanced compared to my beginner level,

I would appreciate if somebody could show me how to do this, I need the relevant code only?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked through his demo activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it, i was missing the android:thumb below:

```
<SeekBar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:max="10000"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
             android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light"

              android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo" >
        </SeekBar>
```

in drwable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_disabled_holo" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_pressed_holo" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_focused_holo" android:state_selected="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_normal_holo"/>

</selector>
```

and:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_track_holo_light"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_secondary_holo"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
      </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_primary_holo"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

of course you need also the image from there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the theme you must have a "themes.xml" file in your res/values folder with the following code (assuming the library is imported...):

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.HoloEverywhereLight">
    <!-- You can customize the theme here! -->
</style>
```

And in your application's AndroidManifest file, apply the theme:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_launch_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/YourTheme" >
```

And then finally in your activity's main.xml layout, add the seekbar somewhere, as follows:

```
<SeekBar
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:progress="75" />
```